# How to get readable File on Android 11

Tags: android-sqlite, android-permissions, android-file, android-11, android-storage

Is there any way on Android 11, except asking for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, to get readable File.class of some, non-media, file?

Using [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) and [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile) I can get Uri (both canRead and canWrite return true), but when I convert it to File, both canRead and canWrite return false (exists return true).

Files my App is using are large SQLite databases created by Users on their computers, which I only read (if it makes any difference), but in order to do that, I need File, instead of Uri.

Currently, my options are:

1. Asking my Users to find some way to copy files directly to data/data directory (which is not visible to computers and most file managers)
2. Copying files (using input/output stream) to data/data directory (which means that 500MB file will take 1GB of internal storage on Device)
3. Applying for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, which I doubt Google will approve

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your issue probably stems from `when I convert it to File`. The following is probably also not true `but in order to do that, I need File, instead of Uri`. You mentioned that `canRead` returns true, you also mention `which I only read`. If `canRead` returns true and you only want to read it, what's holding you back...

Comment: I think that you don't understand the problem. I don't want to save Uri, I want to read data from SQLite database.

As I said, my problem is not with SAF,I prompt User for permission along with takePersistableUriPermission(), save it to SharedPreferences, read from it and Uri return true for both canRead and canWrite.